# how to modify chart axis in matlab?

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to put character instead of numbers in XData axis in matlab? 
For example in this chart,
[image: simple chart]

I want to replace `1 2 3` with `string 1 string 2 string 3` for the X axis.

My code is

```
a=bardata ;
b=barerror ;
ctrs = 1:3;
data = a;
figure(1)
hBar = bar(ctrs, data);
markers = {'x','o','^'};
ctr = [];
ydt = [];
for k1 = 1:size(a,2)
    ctr(k1,:) = bsxfun(@plus, hBar(1).XData, [hBar(k1).XOffset]');
    ydt(k1,:) = hBar(k1).YData;
end
hold on
    errorbar(ctr', ydt', b, '.r')
    legend({'Version 1', 'Version 2'}, 'location', 'northeast');
hold off
```

Comment: A simple solution: add `xticklabels({'string 1','string  2','string  3'})` after `hBar = bar(ctrs, data);`. See more [Specify Axis Tick Values and Labels](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/change-tick-marks-and-tick-labels-of-graph-1.html).

Comment: got it.thanks a lot Anthony

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
xticks([1 2 3]);
xticklabels({'string 1','string 2','string 3'});
```

xticks basically tells where to put the ticks and the xticklabels is selfexplaining.

If you need more information on the labeling:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xticklabels.html